# Different alternatives to jQuery scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, compatibility, scrolltop

At the moment, I am learning how to write in javascript and jquery. I am wondering if there are any alternatives that can be used to scroll through (up/down) classes which are in a div (Not the whole body). Thank you in advance for the help.

PS: I tried to use `ScrollTop` but for some reason (I have no idea why) after refreshing the page on Firefox, IE and Edge the script starts to act really weird. For example, if I press button A to scroll to a class called "A" after the refresh when I press the button A it goes to class "C", for example.

PSS: The alternative method can be in javascript or jquery. Doesn't matter.

Best regards,

George S.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, I can share it. However, only the Jquery part of the code. However, I am tired of searching for solutions, that is why I just want an alternative method which hopefully will not have this weird problem.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx32nvn0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an alternative you can use internal links. For use this HTML feauture you set a name attribute to the content section header where you want to scroll like this:

```
<a name="aDiv">A Section</a>
```

and set the href attribute to the ancor link like this:

```
<a href="#aDiv">Go to A Section</a>
```

This is another approach and must be integrated with CSS for getting the result that you want.